# Pandas fillna on datetime object

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to run `fillna` on a column of type datetime64[ns]. When I run something like:
`df['date'].fillna(datetime("2000-01-01"))`

I get: 
`TypeError: an integer is required`

Any way around this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should work in 0.12 and 0.13 (just released).

@DSM points out that datetimes are constructed like: `datetime.datetime(2012,1,1)`
SO the error is from failing to construct the value the you are passing to `fillna`.
Note that using a `Timestamp` WILL parse the string.

```
In [3]: s = Series(date_range('20130101',periods=10))

In [4]: s.iloc[3] = pd.NaT

In [5]: s.iloc[7] = pd.NaT

In [6]: s
Out[6]: 
0   2013-01-01 00:00:00
1   2013-01-02 00:00:00
2   2013-01-03 00:00:00
3                   NaT
4   2013-01-05 00:00:00
5   2013-01-06 00:00:00
6   2013-01-07 00:00:00
7                   NaT
8   2013-01-09 00:00:00
9   2013-01-10 00:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

`datetime.datetime` will work as well

```
In [7]: s.fillna(Timestamp('20120101'))
Out[7]: 
0   2013-01-01 00:00:00
1   2013-01-02 00:00:00
2   2013-01-03 00:00:00
3   2012-01-01 00:00:00
4   2013-01-05 00:00:00
5   2013-01-06 00:00:00
6   2013-01-07 00:00:00
7   2012-01-01 00:00:00
8   2013-01-09 00:00:00
9   2013-01-10 00:00:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Note that the reason the OP's code doesn't work is because `datetime.datetime` requires integers to be passed, not a string, and so `datetime(2000, 1, 1)` would have worked.

Comment: @DSM you are right. should work in 0.12 (was thining of ``ffill`` now works in 0.13, didn't work before)

Comment: @DSM does that mean there is no way of putting an alphanumeric category like "missing" or "no data" in a column which is datetime64? Is the best way to fix this to convert it string, replace the null values, then convert it to datetime again?

Answer (score 4):

Right now, `df['date'].fillna(pd.Timestamp("20210730"))` works in [pandas 1.3.1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#datetimes)

Answer (score 2):

This example is works with dynamic data if you want to replace `NaT` data in rows with data from another DateTime data.

```
df['column_with_NaT'].fillna(df['dt_column_with_thesame_index'], inplace=True)
```

It's works for me when I was updated some rows in DateTime column and not updated rows had NaT value, and I've been needed to inherit old series data. And this code above resolve my problem. Sry for the not perfect English )